# getAnywhere("timestamp") finds two functions from within Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to call the `timestamp` function in Rstudio but seem to be calling a version other than the one I want.  `getAnywhere` shows that there are 2 definitions:

```
> getAnywhere(timestamp)
2 differing objects matching ‘timestamp’ were found
in the following places
  package:utils
  namespace:utils
Use [] to view one of them

> timestamp
function(...) .rs.callAs(name,
                                                         hook,
                                                         original,
                                                         ...)
<environment: 0x0000000005f42030>

> timestamp()
##------ Thu Mar 06 15:08:51 2014 ------##

> utils::timestamp
function (stamp = date(), prefix = "##------ ", suffix = " ------##",
    quiet = FALSE)
{
    stamp <- paste0(prefix, stamp, suffix)
    .External2(C_addhistory, stamp)
    if (!quiet)
        cat(stamp, sep = "\n")
    invisible(stamp)
}
<bytecode: 0x0000000005f447a8>
<environment: namespace:utils>
```

Calling `utils::timestamp()` crashes RStudio.  If I just call `timestamp`, it seems to ignore the parameters, though.

```
> timestamp(prefix = "##-ddg-- ", quiet=TRUE)
```

This does not change the prefix associated with the `timestamp`, and it returns output to the console, which it should not do when quiet is true.

This is running R 3.0.1, RStudio 0.97.551, Windows 7 Enterprise service pack 1.

On my Mac, `getAnywhere` gives a slightly different result and the `timestamp` function works correctly.

```
> getAnywhere(timestamp)
A single object matching ‘timestamp’ was found
It was found in the following places
  package:utils
  namespace:utils
with value

function (stamp = date(), prefix = "##------ ", suffix = " ------##", 
    quiet = FALSE) 
{
    stamp <- paste0(prefix, stamp, suffix)
    .External2(C_addhistory, stamp)
    if (!quiet) 
        cat(stamp, sep = "\n")
    invisible(stamp)
}
<bytecode: 0x7fd90b10bdb8>
<environment: namespace:utils>
```

Where is this second definition coming from on Windows?  How do I get R to call the right version?

Thanks for your help.

Barbara

Comment: On Windows RStudio replaces `timestamp` with its own method because the default method has dependencies that aren't met in the RStudio environment (which is what causes the crash you see when you invoke it directly). Its method is a replacement for `timestamp`, however, not a wrapper, and the replacement doesn't support all the parameters of the original. I'd encourage you to report the problem on the RStudio support forum.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I will follow up with RStudio.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments Jonathan answers the **Where is this second definition coming from on Windows?** and **crashing** parts of the question with

> On Windows RStudio replaces timestamp with its own method because the default method has dependencies that aren't met in the RStudio environment (which is what causes the crash you see when you invoke it directly). Its method is a replacement for timestamp, however, not a wrapper, and the replacement doesn't support all the parameters of the original. I'd encourage you to report the problem on the RStudio support forum.

Which you have confirmed on the [RStudio Support page](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201002768-timestamp-function-honoring-the-documented-API?locale=en-us). It is also reported on an earlier [RStudio support thread](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200655683-Error-in-history-function-not-supported-in-RStudio).

Unfortunately, RStudio's bug database looks to be internal so you will need to monitor it by following the [commit history](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio) or the *Release Notes* for the [latest version](https://www.rstudio.com/ide/download/desktop) or the [preview release](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/download/preview).

Answer (score 1):

You have two functions in your library which are called `timestamp`, to select one, use square brackets `[]` to select the required package as suggested. E.g. `getAnywhere(timestamp())[1]` or `getAnywhere(timestamp())[2]`